# How use python subprocess.call, sending copy of stdout to logfile, while detecting result of first command

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

My python script needs to invoke a program, detect if it failed (eg, `result != 0`) and send the output of the program to both stdout like normal plus a log file.

My default shell is bash. I'm using Python 2.7.9

To send output to both stdout and a file I'd normally use `tee`:

```
result = subprocess.call('some_program --an-option  | tee -a ' + logfile , shell=True)
```

However, the pipe in bash will return true even if the first command fails, so this approach fails to detect if the command fails.

If I try to use `set -o pipefail` in the command (so that the result will indicate if the first command fails) like this:

```
result = subprocess.call('set -o pipefail && some_program --an_option  | tee -a ' + logfile , shell=True)
```

I get the error `/bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail`

Is there a way in python to invoke a command, send the output to both the normal stdout console and a logfile, and still detect if the command failed?

Note: we have to continue sending some_program's output to stdout since stdout is being sent to a websocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the error /bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail

Pass `executable='/bin/bash'` otherwise `/bin/sh` is used.

You could implement `tee` in pure Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

chunk_size = 1 << 13    
p = Popen(["some_program", "--an-option"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
with p.stdout, open('logfile', 'ab') as logfile:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: p.stdout.read(chunk_size), b''):
        sys.stdout.write(chunk)
        logfile.write(chunk)
if p.wait() != 0:
    raise Error
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference would to to send stdout to a pipe, and then read the pipe in the Python code. The Python code can write to stdout, a file, etc as required. It would also enable you to set shell=False as setting it to True is a potential security issue, as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> *However, the pipe in bash will return true even if the first command
>   fails, so this approach fails to detect if the command fails.*

That is not true.
But I think you mean: the `'some_program --an-option  | tee -a ' + logfile` exit status code always is 0 even though fails in any command part.

Well, using multiple commands (when using `&&` or `||`) or connecting  multiple commands together via pipes causes unreliable exit status code when returned.

Regardless, in the command: `some_program --an-option  | tee -a ' + logfile`  logfile is not written if some_program fails. So you don't need to worry regarding exit code.

Anyway the best way to do pipe along with subprocess is creating [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) objects ans handling `stdout` and `stdin`:

import subprocess as sp

```
STATUS_OK = 0
logfile = '/tmp/test.log'
commands = {
    'main' :   'ls /home',
    'pipe_to': 'tee -a ' + logfile
}

process = sp.Popen(commands['main'], shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)
# explicitly force waits till command terminate, set and return exit status code
process.wait()

if process.returncode == STATUS_OK:
    stdoutdata = process.communicate()[0]
    # pipe last command output to "tee" command
    sp.Popen(commands['pipe_to'], stdin=sp.PIPE, shell=1).communicate(stdoutdata)
else:
    # do something when command fails 'ls /hom' (in this case) fails
    pass
```

That is it!
I the last Popen we invoke [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send the last output from `ls` command to `tee` command STDIN.

In the Python doc there's a tiny tutorial called [Replacing shell pipeline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline), maybe you want take a look.